# Scala: extracting part of a Strings using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, scala

I have a very simple string like this one:

```
"Some(1234)"
```

I'd like to extract "1234" out from it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
val s = "Some(1234)"
//s: java.lang.String = Some(1234)

val Pattern = """Some\((\d+)\)""".r
//Pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = Some\((\d+)\)

val Pattern(number) = s
//number: String = 1234
```

Switch out your regex for whatever you need. `\d+` limits it to digits only.

Comment: what if it didn't match ?

Comment: A `scala.MatchError` will be thrown.

Comment: I have multiple parenthesis-pairs, how do I get the correct match?

Answer (score 7):

```
scala> val s = "Some(1234)"
s: String = Some(1234)

scala> val nums = "[0-9]".r
nums: scala.util.matching.Regex = [0-9]

scala> nums.findAllIn(s).mkString
res0: String = 1234
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, it's possible to pattern match a `String`s by [unapplying a string interpolator](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/StringContext$s$.html#unapplySeq(s:String):Option[Seq[String]]):

```
val s"Some($number)" = "Some(1234)"
// number: String = 1234
```

---

Also note that if the idea is to extract an `Option[Int]` from its `toString` version, you can use the interpolation extraction with a `match statement`:

```
x match { case s"Some($number)" => number.toIntOption case _ => None }
// x = "Some(1234)"     =>     Option[Int] = Some(1234)
// x = "Some(1S3R)"     =>     Option[Int] = None
// x = "None"           =>     Option[Int] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

just another way, playing with the regex. Limit to 4 digits.

```
def getnumber (args: Array[String]) {

  val str = "Some(1234)"
  val nums = "\\d{4}".r
  println (nums.findAllIn(str).mkString)
  }
```